# Setting up scala-logging in a sbt module application

Tags: scala, playframework, slf4j, logback

I have a sbt project where 1 of the projects is a play application also, so:

```
/db
/services
/web (play)
```

So logging is working fine from within the play web app, I can set the log level in my application.conf file just fine.

In my /services and /db project logging isn't currently setup.
I like https://github.com/typesafehub/scala-logging so I need help getting it setup.

So far I have in my dependencies:

```
// logging
  val slf4j = "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % slf4jVersion
  val scalaLogging = "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging-slf4j" % scalaLoggingVersion
  val logbackCore = "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-core" % logbackVersion
  val logbackClassic = "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % logbackVersion
```

Now I went to an object in my /services sbt project and tried:

```
object SomeThing extends LazyLogging {

}
```

1. I'm using IntelliJ and it didn't import anything so I'm not sure what I should do here?
2. Also, if I wanted to create a logger explicitly in a class, what do I have to import and declare?

**Can someone also explain how scala-logging works?**

From what I read it seems to use the same api as sl4j but it uses macros which somehow makes things more efficient by not having to execute the string interpolations if the logging level is disabled.  But it needs (just like sl4j) and actually logging framework, which in this case I am using logback (the same as play).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
libraryDependencies in Global ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.1.0",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.2",
)
```

Comment: I think I have that part fine, I need an example of how to create a class that has logging using the trait and one with explicitly defing the logger (with imports please as sometimes IntelliJ doesn't work)